# HTML Floating or other - getting last element to float next to top element

Tags: html, css

I have a series of elements. The last element is an image. I'm trying to get that image to float to the top, next to the other elements. The goal is to not have any extra wrappers, or use absolutes.

The height of #a, #b, #c and #img are unknown. #img width is 200px, #a, #b, #c width is 800px. Area's height needs to calculate to its contents.

```
<div id=area>
    <div id=a>Text area 1</div>
    <div id=b>Text area 2</div>
    <div id=c>Text area 3</div>
    <img id=img src=# />
</div>
```

If I try css:

```
#a, #b, #c { float: right; width: 800px; }
#img { float: left; width: 200px; }
```

Then image will only float next to #c instead of #a.

Edit: The HTML cannot be changed. No wrappers, no modifications. I'm wondering if there is a trick I don't know about. I have one HTML structure for multiple view styles. I doubt there is a solution but I thought I would ask before giving up.

Comment: What do you mean by float to top ? if you want image at top of this three divs use <br> and place img at first level. or simply you can place in a separate div ?

Answer (score 0):

Make you html like this:

```
<div id=area>
<div id=img>
   <img id=img src=# />
</div>
<div id=a>Text area 1</div>
<div id=b>Text area 2</div>
<div id=c>Text area 3</div>
```

```
#a, #b, #c {width: 800px; } #img { float: left; width: 200px; }
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking to avoid changing the HTML strucure.

Answer (score 0):

> `<div id="area">
>       <img id="img" src="#" />
>       <div id="a">Text area 1</div>
>       <div id="b">Text area 2</div>
>       <div id="c">Text area 3</div>
>   </div>`

CSS:

```
 #a, #b, #c {width: 800px; } 
 #img { float: left; width: 200px; display:inline-block }`
```